# passing a pointer of array of array of char (array of array of strings) in parameters to a function in C and calling the function

Tags: c

I am trying to write and call a function that takes into parameters an array of array of strings in such a way that it will be easy for me to use it column by column.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int N = 14, M = 5;

int main() {
  char *dataset[14][5] = {{"Ensoleille", "27,5", "85", "Faible", "Non"},
                          {"Ensoleille", "25", "90", "Fort", "Non"},
                          .......,
                          {"Pluie", "20,5", "91", "Fort", "Non"}};

  double entropy_syst(char *t[N][M], int tab_length, int ind, char *col_value);

  printf("Entropie du system = %f", entropy_syst(dataset, 14, 4, "Oui"));

  return 0;
}

double entropy_syst(char *t[N][M], int tab_length, int ind, char *col_value) {
  static int cpt1 = 0, cpt2 = 0;
  int i;
  double val1 = 0, val2 = 0, val3 = 0, val4 = 0;
  double entropy;

  printf("\nElement in position 14 2 : %s", *t[13][1]);  // Trying to display

  for (i = 0; i < tab_length; i++) {
    if (strcmp(t[i][ind], col_value) == 0)
      cpt1++;
    else
      cpt2++;
  }

  val1 = (double)cpt1 / tab_length;
  val2 = (double)cpt2 / tab_length;

  entropy = -val1 * log2(val1) - val2 * log2(val2);
  return entropy;
}
```

When I compile it, there is no error but the execution does not provide a result. From my understanding, there is a problem with the way I am passing the array into parameter to the function. I need your help please. Thank you.

Comment: Why is `N` and `M` 50? Shouldn't it be 14 and 5 respectively? And please post a [mcve]

Comment: `printf("\nElement in position 14 2 : %s", *t[13][1]);` should be `printf("\nElement in position 14 2 : %s", t[13][1]);`

Comment: Please i am also trying to copy a part of dataset in another array. For example, i need an array of arrays containing all the arrays of dataset, except those having their first string value at "Pluie".

Comment: Um, what's stopping you from doing it? If you're stuck, try to research and find the solution. If you still can't find a solution, post it as a new question showing your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

You are not *calling* the function. You put the declaration of the function where you are expected to call it. You should call it as

```
entropy_syst(dataset, 14, 5, "some string");
```

You are supposed to get a `double` value from the call, you may choose to store it in some variable.

Comment: Yes i just inserted the function calling. but it does not still work

Comment: Does your `printf` show anything? Also, you'd need to move the function declaration to the top, maybe before `int main()`.

Comment: printf("\nElement in position 14 2 : %s", *t[13][1]);      I removed the * and before t[13][1] and it worked. Thanks a lot